# Why does the grandmother in Rapsittie Street Kids talk in gibberish?

Tags: dialogue, voice-acting, rapsittie-street-kids

There is a scene in Rapsittie Street Kids where the grandmother of the main character would show up, but her dialogue is almost gibberish. Here is an example:

The movie had a lot of high-profile voice actors, so this was not a simple mistake. Was this an audio issue in the movie copies or was there something bigger like perhaps the actress wanted to be no part of the work? Who was the actress who voiced this character?

Comment: This kind of stylistic decision will have been made by the director, not the voice actor. And it is definitely not a production or copying error (the former because the final version will have been watched many times before release, the latter because that's just not possible, or even statistically likely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was, according to the actor (Debra Wilson) that voiced the grandmother, an intentional stylistic choice. She's simply supposed to be elderly and slightly doddery.

> Mad TV star Debra Wilson was one of the names Slater managed to rope in. She doesn’t remember any unusually sycophantic behavior during her work on Rapsittie Street Kids; in fact, she barely remembers the film at all. On the internet, though, her bizarre, glitchy performance as Ricky’s great-grandma has become the most notorious feature of the entire film. **Some people speculate that her audio files were corrupted, but Wilson recalls that she was asked to produce that voice. “They were like, ‘Great-grandma is disheveled; she can’t get her words together,’” says Wilson. “So that had to be in the script. That’s not audio. That’s me. I can tell the difference. That’s me.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Polygon - The making of the worst Christmas special of all time](https://www.polygon.com/2020/12/24/22196527/rapsittie-street-kids-believe-in-santa-cast-crew-making-of)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

According to one of the Producers' daughters in an interview, the grandmother's dialogue was the result of corrupted audio files and no one caught the error in time.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Movies and TV. While this has a bit to improve, this is a good start on a great answer. To make this a better answer, it'll be better if you can edit your question to include the quotes from the interview, and little more information. Have a nice stay here :)

Comment: I've seen lots of uncited references on the internet to this supposed interview, but I can't find any direct links. [My answer above](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/121026/100979) suggests that even if this is what the daughter claimed, the actress who voiced the character has denied that.